# Find value in comma separated string column through query

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, filter, query

I have a field inside a table that contains a string made of the country codes:`IT,GB,US,DU,...` and I need to check if the customer's country (`GB,IT,..`) is inside this string.

I know I can use `CHARINDEX()` in SQL to accomplish this result or retrieve the string, convert it in an array and then check with `in_array`, but I wonder if there is a way (and if it is better) to do this task during the query.

This is my current code:

```
Mage::getModel('razorphyn_country/product')->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('active', 1);
    ->addFieldToFilter('productId', $productId);
```

And `country` is the field that contains the string

Answer (score 12, accepted):

let's say that the country id you are looking for is `$countryId`.
And the field name is `country_id`.
You can add a filter like this:

```
->addFieldToFilter('country_id', array('finset' => $countryId));
```

Below the surface this will convert into the use of MySQL string function [`FIND_IN_SET(str, strlist)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set).